# What are traditional sushi rolls originating from Japan?

Tags: japanese-cuisine, sushi

I'm curious if there are an established traditional sushi rolls from Japan. I came across an article that says there are 86 different types of sushi rolls: https://www.bleepingworld.com/different-types-of-sushi-rolls/

I assume "Texas Roll" and "California Roll" did not originate in Japan, for example.

What are the traditional Japanese sushi rolls?

Comment: Sorry, but to my knowledge there is no sushi legislation which determines which kinds are considered "real". "Authentic" is also a very difficult term, since there is no set point in history after which new kinds become "unauthentic", it differes with an author's interpretation. And even if there were a way to define the category you are looking for, it would end up being a laundry list stile question, which is not something this site can deal with very well.

Comment: I'd assume that "authentic" sushi rolls would come from Japan. Names like Boston Roll, California Roll, and Las Vegas Roll hardly sound Japanese. Food is constantly evolving. Trying to list all the kinds of sushi rolls is as futile as trying to list the all kinds of sandwiches.

Comment: Makizushi, which includes norimaki : hosomaki, chumaki, futomaki, uramaki, and temaki.  Then we have the question if gunkan maki is a 'roll'.  I assume there'd be a name for the makizushi that isn't norimaki (ie, uses something other than nori seaweed for wrapping).  Once you get past that level, it's more like asking 'how many different recipes are there for meatloaf'?

Comment: Doh. I forgot to mention that uramaki isn't Japanese ... it's Californian.  It's the 'inside out' rolls, where it's not nori on the outside.

Comment: The whole "roll" concept--rice on the outside, goopy sauce--is entirely American. Japanese nori maki leave the nori on the outside, and don't sauce them up. Sashimi and nigiri are of Japanese origin.

Comment: Having been to Japan, I can tell you that while they may not have a Texas Roll commonly available, they still do some pretty out there stuff with their sushi which even most Japanese wouldn't consider "authentic". There simply is no answer to this question, unless you will accept "only rolls which contain rice, seaweed, optional soy sauce and wasabi, and a combination of not more than two of: at most one kind of fish/seafood; egg (tamagoyaki, raw quail egg, etc); finely sliced raw green onions". That seems to be the definition of edomae-style sushi, which is as authentic as I think you can get

Comment: About 25 years ago I was in Japan for a couple weeks, guests of steel mills. We had nearly all traditional foods ; Probably had some rolls but they were not common.